# Parse XML with a colon attribute in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I'd have the following XML structure:

```
<entry>
    <id im:id="595831580">blabla</id>
</entry>
```

Now I want to parse the id 595831580.

I tried:

```
$idAtt = $xml->entry->id;
$id = $idAtt->attributes();
$id2 = $id['im:id'];
```

But this does not work :(

How can I fix it?

Comment: if the xml is a string, did you `simplexml_load_string();` it, to convert to an object? what does `var_dump($xml);` show?

Comment: You have to parse XML with an XML parser and create an object out of it to even have a hope of parsing it reliably; show us what you're using

Comment: You first need to register the namespace `im` before accessing the attribute.

Comment: Checkout [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#108029). `$idAtt->attributes("im",true)->id`.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @Passerby

Answer (score 5):

Alright.

You can't use namespace in `offsetGet` method of [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), but you can in [`attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method:

```
echo $xml->entry->id->attributes("im",TRUE)->id;
```

Check out [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#108029) for one more demo.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe something like this

```
$attr = $xml->id[0]->attributes();
echo $attr['im:id'];
```