# PHP Trying to Get Simple XML Attribute Value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is my XML:

```
<WebContent diffgr:id="WebContent1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <orig_inv_no>73</orig_inv_no>
  <inv_no>141</inv_no>
  <inv_type>S</inv_type>
  <content_type>3</content_type>
  <content_type_desc>Test</content_type_desc>
  <content_value>Sample content</content_value>
 </WebContent>
<WebContent diffgr:id="WebContent2" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <orig_inv_no>73</orig_inv_no>
  <inv_no>141</inv_no>
  <inv_type>S</inv_type>
  <content_type>3</content_type>
  <content_type_desc>Test</content_type_desc>
  <content_value>Sample content</content_value>
 </WebContent>
```

I am having a lot of trouble getting the attribute "differ:id" for the node "WebContent"

It seems like it doesn't like the colon in the attribute name. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the attribute is "diffgr:id" not "differ:id" maybe this is your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$xml->WebContent->attributes("diffgr",TRUE)->id;
// TRUE means that `diffgr` is a prefix of the attribute
```

COuld be found here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15546669/2040840